# How can i grant access to mySQL database to other computer within my house?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a beginner in SQL so i'm sorry if the question is too basic.

I just created a database in MySQL Workbench in my computer and i would like to be able to access and modify the database from another computer within my house. I read some solutions but they all require using some external product, is there a way and how can i do this by the MySQL Workbench GUI, or maybe other functionalities from MySQL?

I also installed MySQL community server on the other computer that i would like to connect my database to.

Thanks!

Comment: Obvious first question - are your computers succesfully linked on a network , what OS

Comment: They are not linked actually, both with Windows OS.

Comment: Then how can they talk to each other?

Comment: I mean they are connected to the network, but i have never connected both machines via the network.

Comment: You need to figure that out before asking this..

Answer (score 0):

If it's a home network, and both of you are connected via same router, then you can connect to mysql server on the other device using `http://ip_of_machine_running_mysql:3306`.

`ip_of_machine_running_mysql` should be the ip of the machine running mysql server.

Worth to note that you need to allow remote connection to mysql if you haven't already done so when you were doing mysql installation.

The steps for enabling remote access differs for your os(windows, ubuntu, mac), but you can easily find tutorials and how to's for changing such configuration.

- https://www.brightfunction.co.uk/connecting-to-mysql-server-across-a-local-windows-network/
- https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/